# Firebase Auth - Keep user logged on Node using JS SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a scenario where I have a Node client application that needs to authenticate with Firebase. The Node application uses the Firebase JS SDK (not admin) and I want to ask the user for their username and password only once, and then if successfully logged on I want to persist their session, just like it works on the browser.

How do I persist the user session on Node? I believe I can persist the refresh token that I can get using `user.refreshToken`, but how do I authenticate the user again using the refresh token? I tried calling `auth().signInWithCustomToken(refreshToken)` but that seems to be expecting an ID token, not a refresh token. Can I somehow generate a new ID token with this refresh token?

Comment: Are you just planning to use server side sessions? If so, consider using Firebase Auth's [session cookie management solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)

Comment: @bojeil I am actually trying to use the built-in session management from Firebase using ID Tokens, just like it does on the browser but using Node, without any server side sessions. But if that's not viable I will consider your suggestion, thanks!